# cakephp methods/attributes look up?

Tags: php, api, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP, my first framework. I've been doing some of the basic tutorials provided in the documentation, and I often come across a method or an attribute that I want to know more about. For example:

```
      //App/Model/User.php
      ...
      public function isOwnedBy($post, $user) {}
```

My question is, how do I find more details about any attribute or method? I've tried searching using the internal search but no results. I've also been googling in the hope that that might give me results, but nope. I've tried using the API to look it up, but no results either. Am I doing something wrong?

Understanding what exactly a method does, and an attribute is, makes it much easier to follow the tutorials in my own experience. Especially in the Authentication/Authorization stage, where lots of methods and attributes get introduced without too much explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's part of the core API, then it's documented in the [API docs](http://api.cakephp.org/). Parts of the API are also described in detail in the [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/). To get a more detailed grasp on what's going on you can of course always have a look at the source code.

That specific method however is a custom model method from the CookBooks [Simple Authentication and Authorization Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) example, so you won't find anything about it in the API documentation as it's not part of the core API.

In case the code provided in the examples isn't documented well enough for you to understand it, then you can always ask for further explanation/help, for example in the groups, the chat, etc (see http://community.cakephp.org/), and also here on Stack Overflow if you have a specific questions.